# How to bypass automatic repair on an acer laptop to get to bios?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, bios

When I boot the computer, it automatically goes into repair mode, eventually reaching a screen saying "Reparing hard disk errors. This can take over an hour" (or something like that, the actual text is not in english). The computer hangs at that screen forever (it's been attempted for 24 hours).

I would like to bypass this repair to boot up a linux live cd and see if I can salvage some data. Pressing the customary bios keys (f2, f10, f12, delete, enter, running palm accross keyboard) doesn't seem to work. The live cd/BIOS shouldn't require the use of the hard drive right?

Any ideas on how I could get past this screen?

The laptop is an Acer Aspire V5-531, with windows 8 installed.

Comment: The hard drive is failing, replace it with a new one and install windows, then connect the old drive using a sata to usb adapter to see if you can get to your files.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that's what I'm eventually going to do. But why won't the computer boot into bios? To my understanding, that part does not require a hard drive.

Comment: Because windows 8 does not do a full shutdown, it does a hybrid shutdown, so on restart it boots from the hiberfil.sys file and bypasses the bios routine. You can remove the drive and delete the hiberfil.sys file from the root of the drive, put it back in and you should be able to access the bios now.